# Polymer 1.0: How can I add paper-card heading content dynamically

Tags: polymer-1.0

Is there a way I can create `paper-card heading` dynamically using some property inside `custom element`? Following is what I tried but didn't work. Probably this is not the way to achieve what I want:( I googled for a couple of hours but ended up with nothing!

**Custom Element**

```html
<script>
      (function () {
          'use strict';

          Polymer({
              is: 'nearest-customers',

              properties: {
                  customers: {
                      type: Array,
                      value: [],
                      notify: true
                  },

                  cardViewMaxRecords: {
                      type: Number,
                      notify: true
                  },

                  showFullCustomerList: {
                      type: Boolean,
                      value: false,
                      notify: true
                  },
                
                  headingContent: {
                      type: String,
                      value: 'Custom card heading'
                  }
              },

              ready: function () {
                  this.heading.textContent = this.headingContent
              },

          });
      })();
  </script>
```

**HTML**

```html
<nearest-customers id="nearestCustomers" card-view-max-records="3"></nearest-customers>
...
...
...

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function (e) {
    var nearestCustomers = document.querySelector("#nearestCustomers");
    nearestCustomers.headingContent= "<a href='someurl'><iron-icon icon='fa:arrow-left'></iron-icon></a>&nbsp;This is a new content";
    
  }
</script>
```

My objective is to put an `iron-icon` before the heading text and the icon can be used as a `link` to somewhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way, but I just added the styles and structure:

```
      <div class="header paper-card">
          <div class="title-text paper-card">
          <iron-icon icon="book"></iron-icon> Reading List 
          </div>
      </div>
```